# Node.js application on private linux hosting

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, hosting

I have a dedicated linux hosting with Red Hat OS running on it.

I followed [this](https://hostiso.com/how-to-install-setup-node-js/) link and installed Node.js (10.4.0) and npm on it. I also installed git and cloned my git repository. There are 3 problems I am facing

**Problem 1**

If I do **node -v** on the root folder it gives me v0.11.9, if I do **npm -v** on root it gives me 1.3.15

However if I do **~/nodejs/bin/node -v** it gives the correct version v10.4.0 and if I do **~/nodejs/bin/npm -v** it gives me an error:

```
/home/realedu7/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:123:16)
    at node.js:1027:3
```

Below is an image of my terminal showing the issue:
[image]

What is the issue with update-notifier?

**Problem 2**

When I try to run my application by going into the realedu-app project folder and doing

```
node app.js
```

it gives me the following error:

```
module.js:333
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/realedu7/realedu-app/app.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
```

Clearly the express module is not installed for my node.
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to use [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora) to install and setup node and npm

**Problem 1:** There are conflict between older nmp lib and newer npm lib. Your new npm still pointing older version of node(which does not support `let`), you need to set path of you new nodejs to fix this issue

**Problem 2:** You need to install all modules used in code, if you have already added in `package.json` then just need to run `npm install`  otherwise you have to specify module name like `npm install express`

Comment: So do I delete all the node and npm folders from there and restart using the given documentation?

Comment: Ok so I installed nvm and then installed node. now when I do node -v and npm -v I get , v8.11.2 and 5.6.0. So I guess my global node and npm is up to date. Should I delete that nodejs folder I created? Also where do I run the npm install express command from? Within the node project ?

Comment: Yes, you should delete nodejs folder as there is no use of that folder and run `npm install` in side project from where you are running `node app.js`